# Unable to stop importing data

Tags: python, qt, import, pyqt4, qt-designer

I wrote a data acquisition code using python, and now I'm trying to interface my code with a GUI application using Qt Designer. My problem is when import my data acquisition code (sensor.py) by clicking startButton on my Main Window the program starts collecting data but I can not stop it by clicking stopButton or even I can't press any other button, and I have to close my main project to stop collecting data.

Here's my main project Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from gpiodialog import Ui_GPIODialog
from savedialog import Ui_SaveDialog


class dataAcquisition(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(dataAcquisition, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


###################The problem is under here###################
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startButton_clicked)
    def startButton_clicked(self):
        import sensor

        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stopButton_clicked)
    def stopButton_clicked(self):
###############################################################



        self.gpioButton.clicked.connect(self.gpioButton_clicked)
        self.popGPIO = gpioDialog()
    def gpioButton_clicked(self):
        self.popGPIO.show()

        self.saveButton.clicked.connect(self.saveButton_clicked)
        self.popSave = saveDialog()
    def saveButton_clicked(self):
        self.popSave.show()


class gpioDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_GPIODialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(gpioDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        flags = QtCore.Qt.Drawer | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.gpioOKButton.clicked.connect(self.acceptOKButtonClicked)

    def acceptOKButtonClicked(self):
        self.close()        


class saveDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_SaveDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(saveDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        flags = QtCore.Qt.Drawer | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.saveOKButton.clicked.connect(self.acceptOKButtonClicked)

    def acceptOKButtonClicked(self):
        self.close()        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = dataAcquisition()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

sensor.py Code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

## Reading data from a photocell sensor

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Tell the GPIO library to use Broadcom GPIO references
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

#define the pin that goes to the circuit
Pin = 7

def RCtime (Pin):
  measurement = 0
  #Output on the pin for # Discharge capacitor
  GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.OUT)
  GPIO.output(Pin, GPIO.LOW)
  time.sleep(0.0001)

  GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.IN)
  # Count loops until voltage across capacitor reads high on GPIO

  while (GPIO.input(Pin) == GPIO.LOW):
    measurement += 1
  return measurement

# Main program loop
i = 1
while True:
    file1 = open("Data%i.txt" %i ,"w")
    i += 1 
    c = 1
    while c <= 50:
        print RCtime (Pin)*1.000
        c += 1
        file1.write(str(RCtime (Pin)))
        file1.write("\n")

    else:
      file1.close()
```

I tried to use Threading and edited my code as shown below, now I am getting the data printed but my GUI app doesn't pop up! Does anybody knows why?

I will be grateful if someone can help.

The new code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
import sensor

class dataAcquisition(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(dataAcquisition, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadclass.start()

    def Sensor(self):
        val = sensor.RCtime(Pin)


class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        val = sensor.RCtime(Pin)
        print val


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = dataAcquisition()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
###################The problem is under here###################
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startButton_clicked)
    def startButton_clicked(self):
        import sensor

        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stopButton_clicked)
    def stopButton_clicked(self):
###############################################################
```

You're right. The problem is here.

You define start button callback `startButton_clicked` as

```
def startButton_clicked(self):
    # Data acquisition
    import sensor
    # Connect stop callback
    self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.stopButton_clicked)
```

The issue here is that the data acquisition script ends up with an infinite loop so it never returns and the GUI never gets the control back.

You should the use the sensor script in a thread, so that it doesn't block the GUI while running.

BTW, note you could make all callback connections at `__init__()` time. If you don't want the stop button to be active when no task is running, just make it inactive using [set_enabled(False)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop).

Here's what the thread could look like:

from threading import Thread
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

```
class Sensor(Thread):

    def __init__(self, stop_request):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stop_request = stop_request

    def run(self):
        # The run method is called internally when you call Sensor.start()
        # and is executed in a separate thread

        # Tell the GPIO library to use Broadcom GPIO references
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

        #define the pin that goes to the circuit
        Pin = 7

        def RCtime (Pin):
            measurement = 0
            #Output on the pin for # Discharge capacitor
            GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.OUT)
            GPIO.output(Pin, GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.0001)

            GPIO.setup(Pin, GPIO.IN)
            # Count loops until voltage across capacitor reads high on GPIO

            while (GPIO.input(Pin) == GPIO.LOW):
                measurement += 1
            return measurement

        # Main program loop
        i = 1
        # Run until stop request event is set
        while not self.stop_request.is_set():
            # Note you can use this syntax for file handling
            with open("Data%i.txt" %i ,"w") as file1:
                # And you can use range to loop 50 times,
                # no need to use explicit loop variable like in C
                for _ in range(50):
                    print RCtime (Pin)*1.000
                    file1.write(str(RCtime (Pin)))
                    file1.write("\n")
            i += 1

        # Clear stop request event
        self.stop_request.clear()
```

Plug the `Sensor` object in your main code like this:

```
from sensor import Sensor
from threading import Event

class dataAcquisition(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(dataAcquisition, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        # Initialize stop request event
        self.stop_request = Event()

    def startButton_clicked(self):

        # Initialize thead, passing the event
        self.sensor = Sensor(self.stop_request)

        # Start thread
        self.sensor.start()

    def stopButton_clicked(self):
        # Set stop_request event to ask the thread to stop
        self.stop_request.set()
```

I let you figure out the GUI part. This is another story. (There can be a little time between the moment the user pushes the stop button and the moment the thread actually stops, so in an ideal world, you may want to wait for the thread to actually finish before you re-enable the start button. Search for `Thread.join()`.)

This code is totally untested. I'm not `Threading` expert. I just figured that out reading the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

If it does not work right away, it should have least be a good hint.

Comment: Thanks Jérôme for your answer. I tried to use Threading and edited my code as shown up "after editing the question", now I am getting the data printed but my GUI app doesn't pop up! do you know why?

Comment: Did you modify sensor.py? Because if you didn't, you still have the same issue. When importing sensor, the whole sensor.py script file gets executed. Since this happens at the beginning of your main script, you never even reach class dataAcquisition declaration. There are several ways to make things right, but basically the idea is to put everything in objects to avoid executing stuff at import time. The sensor object can be the thread itself or a dedicated object, I suppose. And this can be done in the main file or a separated one, obviously.

Comment: I really tried a lot by editing sensor.py and my new ThreadClass class, but unfortunately it did not work! I am new with python and I will be really grateful if you could help me.